# Was Project Pegasus about the light-speed engine?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

The real question is, did SHIELD know it was for that specific result - the light speed engine?

Or was this secretly a Mar-Vell project, or, a Kree project?

What did SHIELD think it was about?

Was it simply about knowing more about the Tesseract?

Or...was it more about weaponizing it (as Dr. Zola did - in Captain America - The First Avenger)?

Answer (score 1):

> Did SHIELD know it was for that specific result - the light speed engine?

## No.

They were trying to investigate the properties of the Tesseract for it's power potential and to create weapons.

> In the comics, Pegasus stands for "Potential Energy Group/Alternate Sources/United States,"
>
> <sup>[**ComicVine**](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/03/08/captain-marvel-what-is-project-pegasus-/)</sup>

Mar-Vell was using her knowledge of the Tesseract for her own reasons

> Captain Marvel plays off of the events established in The Avengers, showing that the Air Force also had a hand in SHIELD's work at Project Pegasus under **Dr. Wendy Lawson, who was experimenting on the Tesseract as well for entirely different reasons**. We find out that she was creating a Light-Speed drive for space travel.